# Print my subreports horizontally with the detail band

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a report containing a subreport which must be print horizontally.

For example

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                    Master Report
-------------------------- -------------------------- --------------------------
|        Subreport 1     | |       Subreport 2      | |       Subreport 3      |  
-------------------------- -------------------------- --------------------------
-------------------------- -------------------------- 
|        Subreport 4     | |       Subreport 5      |   
-------------------------- -------------------------- 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The subreport (1,2,3,4 and 5) are coming from the same subreport (just different values inside) which is in my Detail band. I set the number of columns to 4 (I need 4 columns)

I tried to set the option "Print order" to "Horizontal" but I have the exception :
    Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: Subreport overflowed on a band that does not support overflow.
I searched about it on forums and they said to put "Print order" on "Vertical" to fix the issue. 
So I am running in circle.

Is there a way to deal with this overflow thing while keeping the horizontal printing ?

The purpose of all this is to generate different barcodes in each subreport and to print using the full page to make stickers

Comment: Show the report code. If you can't, then show a minimal working example that illustrates the problem.

Comment: I need this solution. Have you solved??